# Javascript - toggle 2 divs when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am doing this via asp controls to which when the checkbox is checked, i want it to display an if yes.. and when unchecked i want it to display the if no, and hide the if yes

i have done the following javascript but am not too sure why it isnt working:

```
<script>
    var checkboxTest = document.getElementById('cbIsthereanofficialofVETmobilityinthecountry');
    var hide = document.getElementById(hide);
    var show = document.getElementById(show);
    if (checkboxTest.checked) {
        hide.style.display = 'block';
        show.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        hide.style.display = 'none';
        show.style.display = 'block';
    }

</script>
```

And the controls are:

```
<uc1:CheckBox runat="server" class="CheckBox123" ID="cbIsthereanofficialofVETmobilityinthecountry"  LabelWidth="645" Width="50" />

       <div id="show" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="display: none;">
           <uc1:TextBoxBootstrap runat="server" Height="50" ID="txtIsthereanofficialofVETmobilityinthecountryifyes" />
       </div>

       <div id="hide" class="hidetest" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="display: none;">
           <uc1:TextBoxBootstrap runat="server" Height="50" ID="txtIsthereanofficialofVETmobilityinthecountryifno" />
       </div>
```

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

- You need to have an event handler on the checkbox, which should trigger when you toggle the checkbox. And all of your code should be inside its callback.
- `document.getElementById(hide);` in this `hide` should be a string instead.

See the code below:

```
var checkboxTest = document.getElementById('cbIsthereanofficialofVETmobilityinthecountry');

checkboxTest.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    var hide = document.getElementById("hide");
    var show = document.getElementById("show");
    if(this.checked) {
        hide.style.display = 'block';
        show.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        hide.style.display = 'none';
        show.style.display = 'block';
    }
});
```

Comment: So what would i be adding to the checkbox control? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: You dont need to add anything there.. This should just work fine.. replace the content of script tag with this code..

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, should there be a src in the script tag?